# Programa usando listas en Python

Tags: python

Estoy arrancando en la programación y me piden hacer este programa:

> Rellenar una lista con números enteros entre 0 y 100 obtenidos al azar e imprimir el valor mínimo y el lugar que ocupa.
>
> Tener en cuenta que el mínimo puede estar repetido, en cuyo caso deberán mostrarse todas las posiciones que ocupe. La carga de datos termina cuando se obtenga un 0 como número al azar, el que no deberá cargarse en la lista.

Les dejo lo que intente hacer:

```py
lista = []

i = 0
menor = 9999999
cont = 0

while i <= 100:
    x = int(input("Ingrese un numero al azar: "))
    
    lista.append([x])
    
    if x < menor:
        menor = x
    
    if x == menor:
        cont = cont + 1
    
    i += 1

def imprimirlista(lista):
    largo = len(lista)
    for menor in range(largo):
        print(lista[menor], end=" ")
    print()
    
print("El minimo es: ", menor, "y se encuentra en el lugar: ", cont)

imprimirlista(lista)
```

Comment: Más que pedir el número 100 veces en la variable X, investiga cómo obtener números aleatorios en python, pásalos a int y luego lo tratas a tu parecer. Y para el print, lo que puedes hacer es ordenar la lista de menor a mayor y obtener los N primeros números que sean iguales al primero.

Comment: Si, sabia que hay una forma de el programa suelte un numero al azar pero, como todavía no la vi, no la puedo usar en ese programa. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

La solución es más simple.

Para el ingreso de números simplemente iremos agregando los valores a la lista. Notese que la forma correcta de hacerlo es con `lista.append(x)`. Esto crea una lista de valores numéricos, mientras que `lista.append([x])` crea una lista de listas, cada una con un sólo elemento.

Este código agrega valores a la lista hasta reunir 100 elementos o ingresar uno que valga 0. Notese que no necesitamos una variable separada para llevar el largo de la lista; basta con `len(lista)`.

```
lista = [] # Lista de numeros.
x = 1

linea = 0
while len(lista) < 100 and x:
    linea += 1
    x = int(input(f"{linea}. Ingrese un numero al azar: "))
    if x:
        lista.append(x)
```

Una vez completada la lista, calcular el número menor se reduce a `min(lista)`. Para detectar las posiciones donde ocurre el menor, utilizo comprensión de listas, formando una nueva lista `pos` con las posiciones (en base-1) donde ocurre el menor valor.

```
def imprimirlista(lista):
    menor = min(lista)
    print("El minimo es ", menor, "y se encuentra en los lugares: ", end=' ')
    pos = [i + 1 for i in range(len(lista)) if lista[i] == menor]
    print(pos)
```

**Demo**

```
1. Ingrese un numero al azar: 3
2. Ingrese un numero al azar: 4
3. Ingrese un numero al azar: 5
4. Ingrese un numero al azar: 6
5. Ingrese un numero al azar: 3
6. Ingrese un numero al azar: 0
El minimo es  3 y se encuentra en los lugares: [1, 5]
```

Comment: Me funciono de diez, muchísimas gracias por la ayuda :)